# How exactly does a matrix converter work? Is this even a question that could be answered without months of study?

Tags: ac, power-electronics

I learned a while ago about the [matrix converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-to-AC_converter#Matrix_converters), a type of power electronic device that, I'm told, does direct AC-to-AC conversion without an intermediate DC step. I'm told it can convert input AC voltage at any frequency to any other frequency (presumably there's an implied "within reason" there) without an intermediate DC stage.

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around how exactly this works, and would appreciate someone elucidating it for me. In particular, control algorithms for this type of device seem like they'd be incredibly complex. (perhaps they are, and that's why I haven't seen one used in practice?)

...as an aside, I'm also curious to know where the name "matrix converter" comes from, if anyone can answer that as well.

Comment: A quick web search gave me a beautiful master thesis on the subject with lots and lots of diagrams: [here](https://core.ac.uk/reader/37342660)

Comment: Yes, oldfart's link is the one I read a while ago, very good. Just remember that with 3 phases, there's always power available between two of them, no need for a DC link capacitor to hold you over the zero crossing. Why Matrix? See figure 2-8 on page 12.

Comment: @Neil_UK Ooh, does it only work on three-phase then? That would make sense.

Comment: @Hearth Only with multi-phase, which the wiki article says but doesn't emphasise, and only for inductive loads which do their own current filtering, which the wiki article doesn't say explicitly at all, although it's implicit in a number of the references. Figure 4 isn't really drawn to suggest a 3x3 matrix, is it, I'm toying with the idea of redrawing it

Comment: @Neil_UK Does it need an inductive load? Is there some reason it doesn't work with an LC filter and a resistive load?

Comment: @Hearth The matrix converter needs to see an inductance on its output, either a motor, or the input L of an LC filter.

Comment: @Neil_UK Okay, that makes sense.